# Using Maxwell Relations or any other mathematical or thermodynamic relations, prove that (∂Cp/∂P)=−T(∂^2V/∂T^2)

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Prove that:
 $$\left(\frac{\partial Cp}{\partial P}\right)_T = -T \left(\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial T^2}\right)_P$$

Since $Cp = (\frac{\partial H}{\partial T})_P$

$$\left(\frac{\partial Cp}{\partial P}\right)_T = \frac{\partial}{\partial P} \left(\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P\right)_T$$

Using the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial P} \left(\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P\right)_T = \frac{\partial}{\partial P} \left(\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}\right)_P\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_P\right)_T$$

From:

$dH = TdS + VdP$

$(\frac{\partial H}{\partial S})_P = T$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial P} \left(\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}\right)_P\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_P\right)_T = \frac{\partial}{\partial P} \left(T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_P\right)_T$$

Expanding the derivative:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial P} \left(T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_P\right)_T = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_S \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_P + T\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T\right)_P$$

By the cyclic rule and subsequently Maxwell Relations:

$$-\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_S \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_P = \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$$

Substituting these in, I get an extra term:

$$\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P-T \left(\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial T^2}\right)_P$$

Above was my first approach to the question. Why do I get an additional term in this version of the proof?

I was able to later prove it by finding $\frac{\partial H}{\partial P} = T\frac{\partial S}{\partial P} + V$ and solving using similar steps to get the correct answer.

Comment: The first part of the demonstration is not necessary since by definition the specific heat at constant pressure is the derivative of the entropy with respect to temperature multiplied by the temperature and you can get it easily by just taking the diffential of entropy with (T, P) as variables

Concerning your problem, by quickly looking I believe you don't need to expend the derivative since T is constant

Comment: A good equation to start with is $$dH=C_pdT+\left(V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right)dP$$

Comment: Thank you very much Tom! I guess it would be correct to assume that there is no expansion of the derivative.